# Pharma Hack Assistance Needed - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I recently used Wordfence to fix (I think) what appears to be a pharma hack on one of my sites. I additionally removed all of the sitemaps from Google Search Console. However, I am getting an error when navigating to the site from google search. I can access it fine when directly navigating to it.

The error is below:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /Detox/collaborators-belts.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at www.detoxnightclub.com Port 80
```

Additionally, in Google Search Console, there are 87 products with errors listed that are all related to the pharma hack. What other steps can I take to get rid of those?

Comment: While I won't opine specifically as to the on-topicness of the question for Stack Overflow itself, you may wish to consider deleting and re-posting this inquiry at SO's sister site, [Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com). They frequently handle inquiries regarding Google Search and the [Google Search Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search-console).

Comment: You may wanna read this https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fix-soft-404-error-in-Google-search-console?share=1